# How to align a table inside Eclipse view

Tags: eclipse, tree, swt, jface

Using SWT and JFace I created a table with a treeview in its the first column and placed it in a view. 
The table is displayed in the right half of the view even though I have left all its design features to the default ones.

```
    private FormToolkit toolKit =null; 
    private ScrolledForm form = null;
    private TreeViewer viewer;
    private FeatureForm viewform;
    private Layout layout;
    // ^^^ these were declared outside of the function that creates the table 
    toolKit =   new FormToolkit (parent.getDisplay());
    viewform=   new FeatureForm(parent, toolKit,this);
    viewer  =   viewform.getTreeViewer();
    form    =   viewform.getForm();
    layout = form.getLayout();
    final TreeViewer viewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER| SWT.FULL_SELECTION );
    viewer.getTree().setLinesVisible(true);
    viewer.getTree().setHeaderVisible(true);
    final TreeViewerFocusCellManager manager = new TreeViewerFocusCellManager(viewer,new FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter(viewer));    
    ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy actSupport = new ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy(viewer) {
        @Override
        protected boolean isEditorActivationEvent(ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent event) {
        return event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.TRAVERSAL
            || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_DOUBLE_CLICK_SELECTION
            || (event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.KEY_PRESSED && ( event.keyCode == SWT.CR || event.character == ' ' ))
            || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.PROGRAMMATIC;
        }
    };
    TreeViewerEditor.create(viewer, manager, actSupport, ColumnViewerEditor.KEYBOARD_ACTIVATION | ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_MOVE_TO_ROW_NEIGHBOR| ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_HORIZONTAL|  ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_VERTICAL);    
    final TextCellEditor textCellEditor = new TextCellEditor(viewer.getTree());
    final CheckboxCellEditor checkboxCellEditor = new CheckboxCellEditor(viewer.getTree());

        TreeViewerColumn column = new TreeViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
        column.getColumn().setWidth(200);
        column.getColumn().setMoveable(false);
        column.getColumn().setText("RSI");
    //the other columns are generated the same way, only the label and content provider differs
```

I printed on the console all the alignments and the coordinates of the tree, the first column, the viewer, the form and the results are all {0, 0} and the column's alignment is SWT.LEFT, apparently.
I use Eclipse Juno, and JavaSE-1.7 for this project.

How can I fix that?

Comment: can you provide a picture? Also, I find `WindowBuilder` a really good tool for Eclipse UI help.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img538/8707/zEyc7n.png